# Dirichlet Problem with piecewise smooth boundary

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Suppose a domain $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R^2} $ with $ \partial \Omega $. For $ f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^2}) $, the dirichlet problem is to find $ u $ with $ \Delta u = 0 $ in $ \Omega $, and $ f = u $ on $ \partial \Omega $. What are the existence and regularity theorems for classical solutions $ u $ in the case that $ \partial \Omega $ is not smooth, but only piecewise smooth?

I am not sure exactly where to look for these results beyond just knowing the standard references, and I am a little overwhelmed by this. I would grateful if someone could put point me in a better direction.

Comment: Could you please define what is a strong solution?

Comment: Sorry, I meant classical. Thank you.

Comment: Is your boundary so bad? It is Worth to note that if the boundary is $C^{0,1}$, i.e. Lipschitz, then you have a classical solution in the sense that $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ and satisfies it pointwise. Take a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440087/dirichlet-problem-with-piecewise-smooth-boundary?noredirect=1#comment943172_440087

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you take the Perron method, you always have existence (take, for example, the pointwise supremum of all subharmonic functions that lie below $f$ on $\partial \Omega$), and for harmonic functions you always have interior regularity (see, for example, the interior Schauder estimates in Gilbarg-Trudinger, Chapter 4 or Chapter 6).

When the boundary is no longer smooth, what you may have are convergence issues - does your solution converge to the boundary value? If so, how quickly? That is settled by whether there is a barrier about that boundary point (Gilbarg-Trudinger also has a discussion of what this means more precisely in Chapter 2, Section 8 - "The Method of Subharmonic functions"), which relates to the geometry of that boundary point - this is quantified by the Wiener criterion.

(Update): The following paper may be useful: http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF00281357.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Before I work things through, maybe you can answer off the top of your head: for piecewise smooth boundaries, say for example polygonal regions, I think it is true that the domain is not $ C^{2,\alpha} $ for any $ \alpha \in (0,1) $. Nonetheless, there is a barrier at the corner points. In this case, is there still a global Schauder estimate/bound?

Comment: I would guess, for piecewise smooth arcs, that as long as the interior angles are positive (that is to say, no cusps where the arcs meet), you should be able to get a global Schauder bound.

Comment: I have found a paper which I think gives substance to that intuition - I've added the link to the answer.